# problema "same name are not supported" c#

Tags: c#

Buenas gente tengo un problema al estar programando en `C#` para llenado de formulario de postes me sale un error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Código**

```
using System;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data;

namespace CapaDatos{

    public class IngresoPoste {
       private dbConxion conexion2 = new dbConxion();
          MySqlCommand comando2 = new MySqlCommand();
          public void agregarPoste(String codPos1, String tipRed1, 
                                   String mater1, String estado1,
                                   String direc1, String propi1, 
                                   double puntoX1, double puntoY1, 
                                   String fot11, String fot21, 
                                   String fot31, String obs1)
        {
            try
            {
                comando2.Connection = conexion2.AbriConexion();
                comando2.CommandText = ("proc_insertar_poste");
                comando2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                comando2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codPos", codPos1);
                comando2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tipRed", tipRed1);
                comando2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mater", mater1);
                comando2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@estado", estado1);
                comando2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@direc", direc1);
                comando2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@propi", propi1);
                comando2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@puntoX", puntoX1);
                comando2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@puntoY", puntoY1);
                comando2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fot1", fot11);
                comando2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fot2", fot21);
                comando2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fot3", fot31);
                comando2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@obs", obs1);
                comando2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                MessageBox.Show("ocurrio un error--->"+ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Bueno lo que estoy haciendo es un programa que consta de tres capas una tiene la conexión de base de datos de `MySql` y como podrán ver estoy llamando la base de datos en `conexion2` para que llame a un procedimiento y lo almacene, pero me sale el error

> same name are not supported

alguna ayuda?

**Procedimiento**

```
PROCEDURE `proc_insertar_poste`(

                    IN codPos varchar(45), 
                    IN tipRed varchar(45),
                    IN mater varchar(45),
                    IN estado varchar(45), 
                    IN direc text, 
                    IN propi varchar(45), 
                    IN puntoX double,
                    IN puntoY double, 
                    IN fot1 varchar(500), 
                    IN fot2 varchar(500), 
                    IN fot3 varchar(500), 
                    IN obs text)
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO poste (   cod_Poste, 
                        Tipo_red, 
                        Material, 
                        Estado, 
                        Direccion, 
                        Propietario, 
                        PUNTO_X, 
                        PUNTO_Y, 
                        Fecha_Creacion_P, 
                        foto1, 
                        foto2, 
                        foto3, 
                        observaciones)

        VALUES (            codPos, 
                            tipRed, 
                            mater, 
                            estado, 
                            direc, 
                            propi, 
                            puntoX, 
                            puntoY, 
                            now(), 
                            fot1, 
                            fot2, 
                            fot3, 
                            obs);
    END
```

Comment: este es un error de MYSQL y no de C#, puedes compartir el codigo de proc_insertar_poste ?

Comment: Si tienes una función y un procedimiento almacenado con el mismo nombre, no funciona.

Comment: Mike ya lo puse el procedimiento, Emiliano no tengo funcion y otro procedimiento con el mismo nombre. Saludos y gracias

Comment: Emiliano Montesdeoca y Mike, me salvaron coloque otro nombre sin barra baja ( _ ) y ya corrio mi programa, gracias por las observaciones saludos y muchas gracias nuevamente.